# Is there a simple way to create a new outbound HttpWebRequest from the inbound request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I need to effect a type of reverse proxy from C# code. (Yes, *I know that IIS has a reverse proxy*, but for several reasons, I need to do this from code.)

So, my controller action will "relay" the inbound request to another URL, then return the response. Kind of like this:

```
public string Proxy()
{
   // This would be an extension method; it's currently hypothetical
   var newRequest = Request.GetRequestToNewUrl("http://newurl.com");

   // Make the request and send back whatever we get
   var response = newRequest.GetResponse();
   using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Something))
   {
      return reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
}
```

The proxied request (to `newurl.com`) should be identical to the inbound request (headers, body, cookies, etc.), just to a different URL.

I've been playing around with it, and it's more complex than I thought. The inbound `Request` is an `HttpRequestBase`, and the proxy request will be an `HttpWebRequest`. They are fundamentally different types, and there's no direct translation between the two. So far, it's been a tedious process of copy and translating properties.

Before I spend a ton of time debugging all this, is there an easier way? There are a fair number of different types to represent an HTTP request:

- `HttpRequestBase`
- `HttpWebRequest`
- `HttpRequest`
- `HttpRequestWrapper`

Is there a way I'm not aware of to simply "reuse" the inbound request, while changing the URL? Or should I continue with my translation from `HttpRequestBase`?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible. You can reuse the Request content from an incoming request and the forward it by creating a new request of your own. Create a new client with the address where the request was supposed to be forwarded. And do a get or post with new HTTP client and just return the result.

```
var client = new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(destinationBaseAddress)
};

return await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, Request.Content);
```

Comment: Does this copy over all HTTP headers as well?

Comment: Yes it does have a Headers property inside it Request.Content.Headers